# How to use regex with two formats?

Tags: regex

A Brazilian phone number has one more digit for cell phone.

How can I use regex to apply a mask to business and mobile phones?

Ex:

1212345678 = (12) 1234-5678

12123456789 = (12) 12345-6789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(\d{2})(\d{4,5})(\d{4})$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AIws05/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4,5})([0-9]{4})$
```